# Error "ionCube PHP Loader" after using composer. Magento 2 showing error. Please advise

Tags: xampp, composer-php, localhost, magento2, ioncube

I'm encountering this message: 
"Site error: the ionCube PHP Loader needs to be installed. This is a widely used PHP extension for running ionCube protected PHP code, website security, and malware blocking.

Please visit get-loader.ioncube.com for install assistance"

I'm getting this message after using Composer/Magento commands (update, upgrade, compile, and deploy). I'm running a localhost install of Magento 2, which is now showing the following message.

"There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 629950493790"

I have looked for other solutions online but these solutions didn't fit. One solution seemed too risky, which was to change the name of my php.ini file to .php.ini (note the dot before). One solution advises to install a version of ionCube with the right PHP version, but since I'm working with PHP 7.0.* I'm not able to find that version of ionCube. I have also looked for the error that matches the error number I was given, but no luck.

I encountered these errors while trying to install a theme. I am new to Magento so I followed a guide that gave me a list of composed commands to go through. I selected the new theme through my admin's Configuration > Design, but noticed the design didn't really push through (cache or compile issue I think? I'm learning, if slowly.) I tried the command "composer update" but got my login credentials wrong.

My environment: Windows, XAMPP, PHP 7.0, Magento 2.2.8

If there are any resources that can help me, please let me know about them, incl. books. I really don't know how to proceed.

C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2> composer update

I want to be able to push the theme's visual changes, and safely and correctly clear the cache and update the files as needed.

Comment: Just wanted to say I figured it out by installing a few different versions of ion cube until I got the right one. Then I followed the readme instructions. From that point things worked exactly as they should

Comment: Loaders are produced to match PHP major version (e.g. 7.0), word size (32/64), platform (e.g. windows), thread safety (used/not used), and on windows also the compiler version. To make it easy, the Loader Wizard script will usually indicate the correct Loader to download and install, so using that is the best first step. Good that you solved it in the end though!